# Pyspark/Databricks for loop apears to run twice for no reason - why?

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I have a pipeline code that processes parquet files iteratively one-by-one in a pseudocode looking like this:

```
def f(files):
   files_list = dbutils.fs.ls(files)
   i = 0
   for file in files_list:
      print(f"\n Trying to read file = {file}, loop index = {i} \n")      
      do_stuff_to_file_and_save_resulting_dataframe_to_curated_folder(file, curated_folder)
      archive_file_by_moving_to_a_different_folder(file, destination_folder)
      i++
f(my_folder)
```

It almost does what it's told - at the end the files folder (made of, say 10 files) is empty, and two destination folders are full. However it does some unexpected behavior at the end of the for loop: it tries to scan read the first file (say, data0) once again, with resetting the index to 0. It looks like the loop is started again without any trigger for it.

```
Trying to read file = FileInfo(path='dbfs:/mnt/my_folder/data0/', name='data0/', size=0), loop index = 0
```

Of course, it throws an exception, because my_folder is empty:

```
FileReadException: Error while reading file dbfs:/mnt/my_folder/data0/part-00000-tid-4845080800878359368-2069f3d0-369c-4c6d-b2a0-50923666af8e-25447-1-c000.snappy.parquet. 
It is possible the underlying files have been updated. 
You can explicitly invalidate the cache in Spark by running 'REFRESH TABLE tableName' command in SQL or by recreating the Dataset/DataFrame involved. 
If Delta cache is stale or the underlying files have been removed, you can invalidate Delta cache manually by restarting the cluster.
```

I'm not sure why the loop appears to be run twice for no reason as the function is called only once. More surprisingly, it breaks after the job is done (the results are saved) There is no SQL table to be refreshed. Everything is made in parquet, and not delta. I've tried resetting and reattaching the cluster. What can be done to resolve that bug?

Comment: I will guess: maybe code has to be executed on `if __name__ == "__main__":`. Maybe it runs it with multiprocessing and every process run your function again - and `if __name__ == "__main__":`. should stop other processes to run it again.